# capturing data in cell arrays in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I am trying to store cell array output of a function into another cell array but couldn't do it. Here is a sample code:

```
clear all; close all; clc;
b1=cell(1,3);
%b1=t1()
[b1{1,1},b2{1,2},b{1,3}]=t1(); %%l1

function [ op1 ] = t1(  )
op1=cell(3,1);
op1{1}=10;
op1{2}=20;
op1{3}=30;
end
```

Function `t1` outputs a 3x1 cell array. In line `l1` I am trying to capture that array into column format array (1x3), but getting error. Anyone knows way to do this?

Comment: `t1` only has one output, you're attempting to store 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are requesting three outputs from `t1` when it only returns one. You should store the output in a temporary variable prior to saving the values into three different cell arrays. To perform that assignment you can use `{:}` indexing to yield a comma-separated list that you can then assign to all the different cell arrays

```
output = t1();
[b1{1,1}, b2{1,2}, b{1,3}]= output{:};
```

Your other option is to actually return *three* outputs from `t1`

```
function [out1, out2, out3] = t1(  )
    out1 = 10;
    out2 = 20;
    out3 = 30;
end

[b1{1,1}, b2{1,2}, b{1,3}] = t1();
```

Comment: You said `You are requesting three outputs from` `t1` `when it only returns one`. Isn't it 3x1 array `op1`? I am confused with cell array and normal array

Comment: @rfer5 Yes it is a 3 x 1 cell array but a cell array is a *single output*. A cell array is just like a normal array except that each element can contain any data.